# How to get two string values in single key hashmap and convert this key into array

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I'm facing the problem with hashmap and arraylist....My problem is...

I have HashMap like this..

```
public class QuestionData {
    private String questionID;
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    public String getQuestionID() {
        return questionID;
    }
    public void setQuestionID(String questionID) {
        this.questionID = questionID;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
while (is another question to add) {
  QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
  questionData.setQuestionID(questionID);
  questionData.setQuestion(question);
  questionData.setAnswer(answer);
  ArrayList < QuestionData > questionDatas = new ArrayList < QuestionData > ();
  questionDatas.add(questionData);
}
int counter = 0;
Button nextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
nextQuestion.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (counter < questionDatas.size()) {
         QuestionData question = questionDatas.get(counter);
         showNextQuestion(question);
         counter++;
     }
     return false;
  }
 });
  showNextQuestion(QuestionData data) {
  data.getQuestionID();
  data.getQuestion();
  data getAnswer();
}
```

But I need the both strings questionid and question in a single key of hashmap, and then I want to convert this single key into arraylist...

After that I want to increment the arraylist when I click on the next button...for next question to display based upon questionid...

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

create data only class for your question

```
public class QuestionData {

    private String questionID;
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    public String getQuestionID() {
        return questionID;
    }
    public void setQuestionID(String questionID) {
        this.questionID = questionID;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

and use hash map with this data structure.

```
    QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
        questionData.setQuestionID(questionID);
        questionData.setQuestion(question);
        questionData.setAnswer(answer);
//        HashMap<String, QuestionData> map = new HashMap<String, QuestionData>();
        ArrayList<QuestionData> questionDatas = new ArrayList<QuestionData>();
        questionDatas.add(questionData);
```

Comment: yes i understood...but how can i get questions based upon questionid to give setText from ArrayList... and then i want to increment the array....Similarly for answer..to setRadioButton Text....help me frnd any solution...is there. frnd

Comment: Im gettin like this in logcat not getting the data I/System.out(462): QuestionDatas:com.example.finalpractice.QuestionData@40600dd0
 for this what i should do frnd...

Answer (score 0):

I like @ViVart's answer a lot better. To add on to his, you can then implement your button:

```
ArrayList<QuestionData> questionDatas = new ArrayList<QuestionData> ();
while (is another question to add) {
    if (firstQuestionParsed) {
        TextView questionID_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        TextView question_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        TextView answer_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        questionID_tv.setText(questionID);
        question_tv.setText(question);
        answer_tv.setText(answer);
    }
    QuestionData questionData = new QuestionData();
    questionData.setQuestionID(questionID);
    questionData.setQuestion(question);
    questionData.setAnswer(answer);
    questionDatas.add(questionData);
}
 int counter = 0;
 Button nextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
 nextQuestion.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (counter < questionDatas.size()) {
             QuestionData question = questionDatas.get(counter);
             showNextQuestion(question);
             counter++;
         }
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Then you just need to implement

```
showNextQuestion(QuestionData data) {
    data.getQuestionID();
    data.getQuestion();
    data getAnswer();
}
```

Comment: Suppose if i have 100 questions and 100 questionid its convert it into arrayList then how can i display for 100 question by increment... like this i should give upto 100...al.add(qArr[0]);......al.add(qArr[100]);

Comment: I actually agree more with @Vivart's solution. I think it's what you are looking for. Then you can easily keep a counter for each question you are on.

Comment: Now my flow of code QuestionData class is correct my frnd..see my edit in above...

Comment: Yes... All of that code looks like it will work, now you just have to add your data to it and put it into your code. :)

Comment: Im gettin like this in logcat not getting the data I/System.out(462): QuestionDatas:com.example.finalpractice.QuestionData@40600dd0
 for this what i should do frnd...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing.. I would suggest putting your actual code update on here so we can see what you have... Then also add the Logcat so we can see the full error.

Comment: With your data... since it's a sizable amount of data (100+ it seems) it would probably be best to import it from a file (csv or something). If you need to know how to do this, then I suggest you search for the answer rather than ask on here since this is another question all together.

Comment: yes i understood..one small doubt frnd..now i want to display the zero index question to give setText..Where can i give this setText after ArrayList..